# Bootstrap datetimepicker - display current and next month in one frame

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, datetimepicker

I need to display a date range like jQuery UI (current month + next month) using Bootstrap 3 and [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker):

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can use this

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
  { 
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: '2013-01-01',
    endDate: '2013-12-31'
  },
  function(start, end, label) {
    alert('A date range was chosen: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
);
```

Comment: Its ok, but I don`t need a range. Only single date. Can you please explain me, how do this with daterangepicker?